# Cannot set up SDK for IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sdk

I am beginner in linux (running Linux Mint 18.3), and trying to set-up my environment for Java development. I've done this several times on my Windows machine, and it always worked, but couldn't make it work for linux.

Running command `java-version` returns the following:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_162"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_162-8u162-b12-0ubuntu0.16.04.2-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.162-b12, mixed mode)
```

Still, when I open IntelliJ, it says that Project SDK is not defined. When I am trying to set it up to the folder `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin` (being the location I found digging into my filesystem starting with command `whereis java`) it says that "The selected directory is not a valid home for JDK". I've added manually the path also to `$JAVA_HOME` and `'$PATH'` but the problem persists.

Comment: Have you tried to change the directory to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/` only ?

Comment: No! I didn't try this. It is working, now. I've tried almost all the possible folders, but not this one. Thank you!

Comment: Possibly your user does not have read rights for that folder where you put the JDK. That is a strange case but you should check. Then you can change rights by running a `chmod` command or through the GUI, but that is another subject and you can google how very easily.

Answer (score 2):

The path you posted says "jre" in it, you need the JDK.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need shoose JDK path
2. without BIN folder, like D:\java\jdk\jdk1.8.0_162

[image]